# spring jaxb2marshaller - how to marshal based on schema?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to learn how to marshal & unmarshal XML to/from Java code, using Spring.  My sample code works for unmarshalling a XML file into my Java classes, based on a XSD file (for validation).

What I'm stuck on and not finding much info on is how to marshal based on the XSD schema file?

Code extracts are:

In the applicationContext.xml file I have:

```
<bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.company" />
    <property name="schema" value="file:test1.xsd" />       
</bean>
```

My main class refers to the jaxb2Marshaller bean.

In my main class I have this to write the XML:

```
private void writeXML() {
    crashScene.getWorkZoneInfo().getWorkZoneDetails().setWorkZoneSpeedLimit(45);  // updates the data previously read in by unmarshalling.

    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("test_output.xml");          
        marshaller.marshal(crashScene, new StreamResult(fos));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Since I have a schema set in the applicationContext, when trying to write the XML I get an Exception:

```
org.springframework.oxm.MarshallingFailureException: JAXB marshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException- with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'FormNum'. One of '{XmlSchemaVersion}' is expected.]
```

If I try writing the XML without using a schema defined, then marshalling works.

How can I write out the XML based on the schema definition??

Many Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I hope this page could help you.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/oxm.html